# The category of medicines that "make you unconscious" or just "prevent pain"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I was wondering what do you call the medicines that are used to:

> 1. make you sleep through the surgical operation.
> 2. make you numb (without making you sleep,) during an operation.

I know "anesthetic medicines" for #1 and "numbness medicines" for #2. But the problem is that many dictionaries have mentioned that "anesthetize" means:

- > To give someone an anaesthetic so they **do not 'feel pain'** during a medical operation."

There is something missing here for me, but I'm not quite confident what that is! I have an intuition that "anesthetic medicines" actually, make you sleep and in this way prevent pain during a more serious process like a critical operation; in more routine operations like: "dentistry operations" where one does not need to get unconscious and just needs to get numb, dentists use "numbness medications".

I was wondering if you could let me know whether I have been right or wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both of your cases, you could call the medicine an **anesthetic** (or if you are using the British spelling, **anaesthetic**). We distinguish between the two kinds of anesthetics with an additional adjective. A ***general* anesthetic** makes a person unconscious, while a ***local* anesthetic** makes one part of their body numb.

The phrase "anesthetic medicines", while not technically incorrect, is not idiomatic; few people would say it that way. It is better to just say "anesthetics".

In your second case, you could also use the adjective **numbing** to describe the medication. For example, if the dentist uses a local anesthetic in your mouth, and that anesthetic takes the form of a gel that she rubs on your gums, you could call it a **numbing gel**. This is a less technical and less formal term than "anesthetic", and it is a very common usage, *especially* when you are talking about over-the-counter medications (medicine that you can buy without a doctor's permission). In fact, if you went to the store and bought a **numbing cream** to rub on some part of your body, it would sound odd to call it a "local anesthetic", even though it technically is.

Comment: Thank you very much @MJ713. Just could you possibly add to your excellent answer regarding "anesthetized" and "numb" too? I think both adjectives can be used in my second case, though I'm not quite sure.